ForegroundServiceType for the foreground service to TTS (Text-To-Speech) | Target SDK 34 support
In my application I am using foreground service to alert users with predefined messages using TTS service (Text-To-Speech) on system broadcast events. It is working fine with target SDK 33 version. Now i have to update the target SDK version to 34 and hence i must have to use ForegroundServiceType. I am not able to figure out which type will be valid in my case.
Note: I am not using mic for any inputs from the user in the background as I have already predefined messages. Only using TTS for output. Message to voice using TTS.
Can someone help me which ForegroundServiceType can i use without violating any google Play policy for the mobile application
Google Defined Types:-
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required

camera
connectedDevice
dataSync
health
location
mediaPlayback
mediaProjection
microphone
phoneCall
remoteMessaging
shortService
specialUse
systemExempted

.
Thanks
